# Android Studio layout design

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

after i drag some elements into ConstraintLayout , there is no element show up on the preview screen , and after run in AVD , all elements was stuck in the top left corner , i am not able to set the position of elements 
[image]
[image]

Comment: paste your `xml` code hear.

Answer (score 0):

You're preview settings is on API 28 which probably you don't. change it to any API Level which you have installed.

[image]

Default behavior of ConstraintLayout is all views inside it moved to top left corner of it. You must use ConstraintLayout attributes or design features to position views where ever you want.

Take a look at this: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)